# Why my OSX pmset do not show hibernatemode 5?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, hibernate

To hibernate my system, all this time (for months) I have been using `pmset -a hibernatemode 5`. This was working great and I had no complaints.

However, recently I was checking out `pmset`'s man page and it turns out there are no mode 5! In fact it instead recommends mode 25. Worried that my using the undocumented mode might harm my battery I have now moved to using mode 25. However, this has turned out to be far slower hibernate than mode 5.

So, can anybody tell me what exactly is mode 5 and how it is different from 25? Is it still safe to use? Why did Apple remove that from documentation?

I have MacBook Pro Early 2011 series, running Lion 10.7.5.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the mysterious "bit 2" is for indicating whether to use secure memory in the sleepfile.

I don't know where this originated, but there are over a thousand results for the exact phrase,

> "This is the same as mode 1, but it’s for those using secure virtual memory."

So I would assume it's somewhere in the documentation. Most of the people saying this are on forums, but I did find something a bit more reputable here,

http://www.macos.utah.edu/documentation/administration/pmset.html

---

**EDIT:** I would assume however, that ***perhaps*** the reason "bit 2" is no longer mentioned in the man page is that activating secure virtual memory encrypts the sleep image for you;
at some point I would like to test this theory though...

Answer (score 1):

5 in binary is 0000 0101 - that is, bits 0 and 2 are set. If you read the pmset man page, it doesn't document any meaning for bit 2, so I suspect it doesn't do anything. If I'm right about this, mode 5 is equivalent to mode 1 (bit 0 only), which just enables hibernation. Mode 25 is binary 0001 1001, which enables hibernation (bit 1) with aggressive pageouts to minimize the sleepimage size.

I don't know of any problems that mode 5 should cause, but the undocumented bit 2 worries me a little. I'd be tempted to try mode 1 and see if that behaves the same. If it does, I don't see any real problem with using it...

Comment: Nopes behavior of modes 5 and 1 are not similar.

Comment: @AppleGrew: In that case bit 2 is doing something undocumented, and I have no idea if mode 5 is safe to use. Therefore, I cannot recommend using it...

Comment: Yup.. because of that I too have stopped setting that bit. However, before this I have using that for last 7-8 months without any apparent issue.